# Will Amaterasu go along with the summoned animal or disappear?

Tags: naruto

Let's say that some summoned animal is being hit by Amaterasu and the summoning is canceled so that the animal can return to its original dimension.

Will the Amaterasu fire go with the animal to the other dimension and kill it or will the animal be able to escape it by going to its dimension?

Comment: i think the flames just drop to the ground but i don't have a source for this assumption.

Comment: IIRC, summoning only transports one from one place to another. Unless 1) Summoning removes any ninjutsu cast on the object being transported 2) The amaterasu user removes it, I think it's possible that someone/something who is caught in amaterasu flames will still keep burning, even when returned/transported back to its original dimension. Will try to elaborate on this, unless someone answers first.

Comment: Note this is completely different from Obito's Kamui where he warped dimensions.By doing so,he could get rid of the flames.But releasing the summoning jutsu is different from warping dimensions,right?

Comment: @GKA "All summoning-based techniques are space–time related, as they warp the targets through a dimensional void to the summoner's location." Source: https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Space–Time_Ninjutsu Kamui and Summoning is not exactly the same, just similar.

Comment: Yeah exactly that's my point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [flames of the Amaterasu](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Amaterasu) are inextinguishable by ordinary means and once any organism is caught in it, they will either have to sacrifice that body part, absorb the  entire Jutsu (if they posses Rinnengan related abilities), or seal the flames away.

In the case of a Snake summon, it could most definitely shed its skin and easily escape the flames of the Amaterasu (which would still be burning the outer skin that it shed). This is evident in the fact that Sasuke was able to escape Itachi's Amaterasu by shedding his skin (a unique ability that he learned from Orochimaru, and Orochimaru learned it in [Ryuchi Cave](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Ry%C5%ABchi_Cave) ).

A slug summon like Katsuyu could survive but the damage will be immense, since she's able to rearrange her entire body into smaller slugs, she could detach out the parts that are consumed by the Amaterasu, by turning into a ton of smaller slugs and sacrifice those parts.

Also, If the animal was summoned by a person who posseses the Rinnengan, the summoner could easily absorb the chakra and remove the flames.

As for all other Summoning animals, Unless they have a unique defensive ability to escape the flames, then the Amaterasu will burn it out from existence. Even if the Animal tries to go back to its main habitat, the flames will still continue until nothing exists.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I thought this was a good answer.

Comment: I'm guessing its cause i  made a mistake in the habitat of the snakes, its the Ryuuchi cave and not Mount Myoboku

Comment: I didn't downvote, and while I agree it is a good answer, my view on it is that a lot of information doesn't directly answer the question. You list countermeasures different summons may have against Amaterasu, but the answer to the question isn't until the final paragraph and feels lost within the text.

Comment: Ah i kinda get what you mean @Wondercricket , the point i was trying to make thou, is that even thou the flames won't disappear from undoing the summoning jutsu, the flames won't necessarily kill a summon if it has a countermeasure.

Comment: @Wondercricket Hm, you do have a point now that you mention it. Still, I guess there is nothing more that can be said apart from the fact that the flames will go with the summoned animal if and only if it will be hit and if changing/traveling dimensions will not remove any ninjutsu cast on the animal being transported, which is possibly the case, given that there are no other details that will be revealed about summoning.

Comment: Using Kamui however, allows a user to escape the Amaterasu @W.Are but then we all know that no summon could ever posses such a powerful time-space ninjutsu

Comment: Agreed. Sorry for the confusion. When I said changing/traveling dimensions, I'm referring to the specific method used in summoning animals you have a contract with, apart from Kamui.